# How to check if it has class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if a the `#load` div has a class also?

```
if (cap > 20) {
$(".p" + (cap-9)).slideto({
    slide_duration : 'slow'
});
}
```

Comment: seems your question has changed dramatically since i answered it..

Comment: @tmsimont even though it is incomplete answer I accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try just adding a class to the button once it's been clicked:

```
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
    cap += 10;
    $(this).addClass("loadmore-clicked");
$(".p" + (cap-10)).addClass("loading");
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".p" + (cap-10)).removeClass('loading');
}, 7000);
    loadfeed();

});
```

And then just see if you have that class on the button below:

```
function loadfeed(){    
    if ($("#loadmore").hasClass("loadmore-clicked")){
      //loadmore was clicked
    }else{
      //loadmore hasn't been clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure i fully understand your end-goal.  that code i provided will have to be modified to work with what you want.  all i've really given you here is a means for checking if that button was clicked in the `loadfeed()` function. the comment i've got there is where you put code that u want when button has been clicked. you might want to add an `else` to that